# How to reset both index and columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in pandas like the one below.

After deleting several columns and rows, the index and columns are not longer a continuous range.

How could it set it back to 0 -> n? I tried `reset_index` without success.

```
     4    12    15     22
5
9
14
26
31
37
```

expected output:

```
    0      1      2      3
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear, is the DataFrame empty? What is the data? How should it be reorganized? Do you simply want to `reset_index`?

Comment: @mozway it is not empty it is full of data in 4 columns and too many rows. but I need to rename the index like this. I can not rename for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to reset both indexes.

You can use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) as `reset_index` does not handle columns:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).set_axis(range(df.shape[1]), axis=1)
```

example input:

```
    4 12 15 22
5   x  x  x  x
9   x  x  x  x
14  x  x  x  x
26  x  x  x  x
31  x  x  x  x
37  x  x  x  x
```

matching output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x
3  x  x  x  x
4  x  x  x  x
5  x  x  x  x
```

Comment: Reading your answers on this site > the pandas Cookbook :)

Comment: @Josh I appreciate your kind comment. I think the pandas doc is quite good though, it surely helped me know the API ;)